# Definition of weakly vanishing

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

In literature concerning dirac constraints, often the word weakly vanishing is used say for example, a function $f$ is called first class if its poisson brackets with all the constraints $\phi_i$ weakly vanishes i.e. $\{f, \phi_i\}_{P.B} \approx 0$. What does it mean for poisson brackets to vanish weakly ? Is there a rigorous definition for weakly vanishing ? Any comments will be helpful.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket): "Two functions on phase space... are **weakly equal** if they are equal when the constraints are satisfied, but not throughout the phase space..." Is this definition consistent with the context where you saw those words?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I think this makes sense.